# How to Remove Emoji from Column value while Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a Column in a table that contains emoji values. I want execute a Select statement to remove all the Emoji from every row if that contains them.

For example, if I have row valve with the following value:

```
"I'm a ‍ ‍ Developer ‍ ‍ ."
```

then the output should be like the following:

```
"I'm a Developer ."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Try This

```
DECLARE  @MyStr nvarchar(255)  = N'Im a ‍ ‍ Developer ‍ ‍ .' 

SELECT @MyStr,LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@MyStr AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'?',''),'  ',' ')))
```

Comment: Note that this will remove all non ascii characters and not just emojis

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
declare  @nstring nvarchar(255)  = 'Im a ‍ ‍ Developer ‍ ‍ .' 
   DECLARE @Result varchar(255)  SET @Result = '' 
   DECLARE @nchar nvarchar(1) DECLARE @position int
   SET @position = 1
   WHILE @position <= LEN(@nstring)
   BEGIN
      SET @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)  
      IF UNICODE(@nchar) between 32 and 255
         SET @Result = @Result + @nchar
      SET @position = @position + 1
   END
 select replace(@Result,'?','')
```